Help illustrating sorting network with tikz
Im trying to illustrate the following sorting network, with tikzpicture. However I can't get the numbers to be above the different linjes and I would like to remove the squares around each number.
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{near start abs/.style={xshift=1cm}}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% input tal 
\node[draw] at (0,1) (a){4}; 
\node[draw] at (0,2) (b){2}; 
\node[draw] at (0,3)(c){5}; 
\node[draw] at (0,4)(d){7}; 
%linjer som viser kanaler 
\draw[very thick] (a) node[above] {} -- (13,1);
\draw[very thick] (b) -- (13,2);
\draw[very thick] (c) -- (13,3);
\draw[very thick] (d) -- (13,4);


\end{tikzpicture}

This is my current output:

This is the illustration I want to make:


How do you want to specify the numbers and the vertical connections? This should be done automatically …

@Qrrbrbirbel im not sure how to do this automatically, but I want the numbers above the line, like on the last picture. Im sorry for the bad response.

For the numbers use in the nodes options draw=none, anchor=south . So the nodes shape is not shown, and its reference point moves from center to lower middle, lifting it virtually up when typeset..

@MS-SPO Thanks, for helping me removing the squares around the numbers. Can u help me, getting the numbers above each corresponding line? :)

anchor=south. Perhaps you need to review your reference points. // How many numbers do you need, i.e. do you have to replicate everything?

Here's a \sortingnetwork macro that takes one optional and one mandatory argument, the latter is your list of numbers. The former can be used to customize just that diagram. It is also used to provide the list of vertical connections with the sn connectors key.
This key will automatically count up and draw a vertical connection in the order that is provided. Various sn … keys/style can be used to customize the diagrams.
The sn colors key accepts a list where each entry has the form <i>:<color> which sets adds the color <color> to the style sn horizontal <i>. This style is used with each <i>th line and as well with the circles on the line.
Code
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{
  every sn picture/.style={x=+7mm, y=+7mm, node font=\sffamily},
  sn node/.style={yshift=-3.5mm, above},
  sn horizontal/.style=draw,
  sn connection line/.style={draw},
  sn connection dots/.style={fill, radius=+1.5pt},
  sn connectors/.style={execute at end scope=\def\sortingnetworkcounter{0}\tikzset{@sn connector/.list={#1}}},
  sn colors/.style={@sn colors/.list={#1}},@sn colors/.style args={#1:#2}{sn horizontal #1/.append style={color=#2}},
  @sn connector/.code args={#1--#2}{%
    \edef\sortingnetworkcounter{\inteval{\sortingnetworkcounter+1}}
    \path[sn connection line] (\sortingnetworkcounter-.5,-#1.5) coordinate (@1)
                           -- (\sortingnetworkcounter-.5,-#2.5) coordinate (@2);
    \path[sn connection dots, sn horizontal #1/.try] (@1) circle[];
    \path[sn connection dots, sn horizontal #2/.try] (@2) circle[];}}
\newcommand*\sortingnetwork[2][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[{every sn picture,#1}]
  \gdef\sortingnetworkmaxcol{0}%
  \foreach[count=\iRow from 0] \row in {#2}{
    \foreach[count=\iCol from 0] \col in \row {
      \ifnum\iCol>\sortingnetworkmaxcol \global\let\sortingnetworkmaxcol\iCol \fi
      \node[sn node] at (\iCol,-\iRow) {\col};
    }
    \path[sn horizontal, sn horizontal \iRow/.try] (-.5, -\iRow-.5) -- (\sortingnetworkmaxcol.5, -\iRow-.5);
  }
  \end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\sortingnetwork[
  sn connectors={0--1, 2--3, 0--2, 1--3, 3--4, 1--2, 1--3, 2--3, 0--1},
  sn colors={2:red, 4:green}
]{
  {9, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1},
  {2, 9, 9, 9, 7, 7, 4, 1, 1, 2},
  {7, 7, 4, 4, 4, 4, 7, 7, 4, 4},
  {4, 4, 7, 7, 9, 1, 1, 4, 7, 7},
  {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9}%
}
\end{document}

Output


Or should the input be column-wise instead of row-wise? What is the rule for the vertical connection? I don't understand the third one: Nothing changes.

This is very good:) The vertical connection is the to inputs switching place, if 9>2 then they switch. The input is column-wise. The Dots/connections look at the different elements in each "line" and checks weather they are greater or less then the element being compared to

Is there a way I can color an individual horizontal line(the dots with the line)? with a specific color?

Nice solution, hard to beat

@Qrrbrbirlbel I get an undefined control sequence error. Do u import other packages then tikz?

@Egelund48 I've added sn colors to get colored horizontal lines (and circles). All packages are visible in the code. However, I'm using an uptodate TeX distribution, do you? What does the log say what control sequence is undefined? I believe \inteval is the newest control sequence in this code. You can replace it with \pgfinteval.

I get the following output: ```Undefined control sequence.
\pgfkeys@code ...\sortingnetworkcounter {\inteval
{\sortingnetworkcounter +1...
l.72 }


@Qrrbrbirlbel I got it working now. Is there any way you can show how u color the vertical lines:) thank you so much for the help

@Qrrbrbirlbel is there any way u could link a pdf or other things, that's shows me how both this macro and other macros work in latex? sorry if its a dumb question. Best regards
